# Why are interfaces called interfaces?

Tags: java, c#

From what I understand so far, an interface is a list of methods that need to be implemented by whoever wishes to use that interface.

If so, would it make any difference to call it a specification instead of interface, or is it more sophisticated than a specification?

Comment: In Objective-C, they are protocols. Its just a word.

Comment: [Specifications are already assigned a meaning in programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification).

Comment: @GeorgeHowarth Yeah, but interfaces can mean other things too. For example, an API can expose no "interface" types at all.

Comment: Agreed, it's just a word. Java's authors had to call it something. They picked the first good term they could find. The next language may use the same terminology or may use something else. (For an illustration of how naming is purely practical in most cases, consider the Algol concept of a "thunk" -- irregular past tense of "think", from the concept that it's  "something the compiler has already throught about".)

Comment: COM and CORBA probably didn't originate the term with that connotation, but for sure they are both responsible for making it a publicly accepted term. In fact, a lot of language support interfaces with exactly the same meaning, and its use is by no means limited to programming.

Comment: @JensG great point about interfaces not limited to programming. I drove a friend's Prius once, and he looked at me funny when I complained about the car's interface. Shifting gears is an interface between the car and the driver, and someone decided to create a new interface when the "automatic transmission" interface has worked well since the 1950s.

Comment: The term "API" (Application Programming Interface) existed long before Java, and given the purpose of Interfaces in Java and in COM/CORBA, it seems an obvious source for the term.

Answer (score 13):

The definition of interface on oxforddictionaries.com is

> A point where two systems, subjects, organizations, etc. meet and
>   interact.

In programming, the 'two systems' are the class that is using the interface (the client), and the class that is 'hidden behind' the interface, i.e. the class that implements the interface. In this way an interface is a point where two classes interact.

Comment: I thought the client is the one  implementing it

Comment: No David, the client is the class that calls the methods defined by the interface.